# Guarantee That a Particular Gradle Task is Run

Tags: gradle

Given the "build.gradle" file below I want to make sure that `stopServer` is run when I call `testServerLifecycle`. Currently if the `runTestOnServer` task fails the build stops. 
If `runTestOnServer` is the only thing on the task graph I do not want to run `stopServer`.

**build.gradle**

```
tast startServer {}

task runTestOnServer {
    dependsOn startServer
}

tast stopServer {}

task testServerLifecycle {
    dependsOn runTestOnServer
    finalizedBy stopServer
}
```

Is this type of functionality supported by Gradle? What can I do ensure that `stopServer` is run when `testServerLifecycle` is on the task graph?

***Details:** Gradle 1.9*

---

### Solution

```
gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { Task task, TaskState state ->
    if (task == runTestOnServer
            && state.failure
            && gradle.taskGraph.getAllTasks().contains(stopServer)) {
        println "----------------- Stopping Server -----------------"
        tasks.stopServer.execute()
    }
}
```

I was not able to use `finalizedBy` on the 'runTestOnServer' task, because I wanted to run 'stopServer' **if and only if** 'stopServer' would have run normaly; using `finalizedBy` would have forced it to run every time.

*It should be noted that this gets run after every task.*

Answer (score 2):

Since `finalizedBy` is not transitive across tasks, it should be applied to the `startServer` task directly. I think something like this should cover it:

```
task startServer { // ...}
task stopServer { // ...}

startServer.finalizedBy('stopServer')
stopServer.mustRunAfter('runTestOnServer')

task runTestOnServer {
    dependsOn startServer
    // ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `afterTask` and remove both stopServer and testServerLifecycle

```
gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { Task task, TaskState state ->
   if (task == runTestOnServer) {
      // clean up, implement stopServer here
   }
}
```

You can also make different rules based on the state of the task like this:

```
gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { Task task, TaskState state ->
   if (state.failure) {
      // Handle the failure
      println "$task FAILED!!!"
   } else {
      println "SUCCESS!!!"
   }
}
```

This should be run after every `task` is executed.

Comment: I don't want to remove `stopServer` and `testServerLifecycle`, I want to make sure `stopServer` runs.

Comment: Will `afterTask` get run after every task? Is there an "after this task" such that it does not get run over and over again?

Comment: I think you want to put the `finalizedBy stopServer` within the `runTestOnServer` task for this to be handled appropriately. You should probably also add `stopServer.mustRunAfter('runTestOnServer')` to complete circle.

Comment: I did get it to work, see updates. Could you clarify in you answer what you mean by "Alternatively, you could use afterTask and remove both stopServer and testServerLifecycle"? I am not sure why I would remove stopServer and testServerLifecycle.